# .focusout() only reading through first if() statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this not reading through both if statements even though they are both true?

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="test">
  Focus out to test prompts
</textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
var disableA = 1;
var disableB = 1;

$('textarea[name="test"]').focusout(function() {
    if (disableA == 1) {
        disableX();
    }
    if (disableB == 1) {
        disableY();
    }
});

function disableX() {
    alert('A is disabled');   
}

function disabledY() {
    alert('B is disabled');   
}
```

Right now it will call for `disableX();` but not `disableY()`

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nCQQm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second function you have called it disabledY, whereas you are calling back disableY()?

Answer (score 2):

You spelled disableY wrong you need to rename it to disabledY()

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with the `if` statements.

Running your code gives the error:

```
ReferenceError: disableY is not defined
```

You have named the second function `disabledY`, and then you try to call `disableY`.